# Drawing a graph using commands throughout TeX file

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have commands of the form `\myedge{u}{v}` spread throughout my TeX file. I want to add a (TikZ) graph at the end of the document containing all the `\myedge` edges seen so far. What would be the best way to do this?

For context, I'm trying to visualize theorem dependencies in my LaTeX document. If the proof of theorem 1 uses lemma 2 and lemma 3, and the proof of lemma 2 uses lemma 4, then I would like a graph of the form `1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4`. To do this, I want to appropriately define `\myedge` and then I'll manually add commands like `\myedge{1}{2}` in the proofs of theorems/lemmas to document this dependency information. I don't want to keep this dependency information separately at the end of the document in a tikzpicture, because that way it would be hard to keep it in sync with the theorems above.

I'm also considering the option of doing this outside TeX, like writing a python script that reads all `\myedge` commands and outputs a TeX file containing a `tikzpicture`, which I'll `\input` in my document. This works, but I'll prefer a TeX-only solution if it's not much more difficult.

A short example that demonstrates what I want. See the comments (`%`) for what changes I want to make but don't know how to:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand*{\myedge}[2]{} % what should I put here?

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{minor} Minor result.\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{major1} First major result.\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
(Long and complicated proof) $\ldots$ \\
Using theorem \ref{minor}, we get that $\ldots$ \\
\myedge{major1}{minor} % document that we used minor in the proof of major1
(more theorem proving follows)
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}\label{major2} Second major result.\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{grand} My grand theorem.\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
(Long and complicated proof) $\ldots$ \\
Since ?, theorem \ref{major1} gives us that $\ldots$ \\
\myedge{grand}{major1} % document that we used major1 in the proof of grand
(more theorem proving follows) $\ldots$ \\
Using theorem \ref{major2}, we get that $\ldots$ \\
\myedge{grand}{major2} % document that we used major2 in the proof of grand
(more theorem proving follows)
\end{proof}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[layered layout, sibling distance=8mm, level distance=8mm]
{
% How do I specify the edges below automatically based on the
% \myedge occurences above?
"Theorem \ref{major1}" -> "Theorem \ref{minor}";
"Theorem \ref{grand}" -> "Theorem \ref{major1}";
"Theorem \ref{grand}" -> "Theorem \ref{major2}";
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of MWE]

**Edit**: It would be great if I could also place the graph at the beginning of the document instead of at the end, but that's not a hard requirement.

Comment: Please, illustrate your problem with an example in form of small but complete document, which reproduce what you do so far and show what like to have.

Comment: If I understand well, `\myedge{#1}{#2}` produces a Tikz picture (graph) and at the end of your document, you want to draw the union of these graphs, am I right?

Comment: @Zarko I have added a small example

Comment: @tom-solid Each edge isn't a meaningful graph by itself. It's the union of those edges that gives us a graph. See the example that I have added now as an edit.

Comment: I have the following unsatisfactory workaround using python: https://github.com/sharmaeklavya2/tex-thmdep/blob/master/tex-thmdep.py. It is unsatisfactory because some of my collaborators may find it clumsy to run python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an interesting problem to approach. Building up the list is pretty simple: We can use macro expansion to start with an empty macro and add in the nodes as they're declared along the way:

```
\newcommand{\edges}{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myedge}[2]{%
  {\let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
  \xdef\edges{\edges "Theorem \protect\ref{#1}" -> "Theorem \protect\ref{#2}";}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Note that we wrap everything in a group so that `\protect` keeps its previous meaning outside the expansion. `\xdef` tells TeX to expand all the macros inside of it and make the definition global. We set `\protect` to `\@unexpandable@protect` which tells TeX that whenever it sees `\protect\foo` that it should expand that as `\protect\foo` (and now you know a little about the underlying mechanisms behind fragile commands and `\protect`).

The first problem arises when we try to pass `\edges` to the `\graph` command. TikZ is expecting a plain token list here and it won't expand the `\edges` macro. Perhaps someone more versed in TikZ than I am can offer a better solution, but I ended up using a variation on the command that we did before to simply create a new macro, `\mygraph` which will create a macro that wraps up `\graph` with the `\edges` expanded as above:

```
\newcommand{\makegraph}{%
  {\let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
  \xdef\mygraph{\protect\graph[layered layout, sibling distance=8mm,
    level distance=8mm]{\edges};}%
  }%
}
```

(this goes just before the `\makeatother` when you put the above in your document preamble).

Now, you can at the end of your document write

```
\makegraph

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \mygraph
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And get your desired result.

I had hoped that I could just include the `tikzpicture` environment inside `\makegraph` and further simplify the results, but when I tried that, I got

[image: All the commands disappeared and it shows tikzpicture [layered layout, sibling distance=8mm, level distance=8mm]”Theorem major1” -> ”Theorem minor”;”Theorem grand” -> ”Theorem major1”;”Theorem grand” -> ”Theorem major2”;;tikzpicture]

instead of the expected graph, so I assume that some of the Lua magic that doesn't allow us to just throw `\edges` into the argument to `\graph` also doesn't let us wrap up a `tikzpicture` environment in a macro. In any event, it's past my bedtime so I'll leave this where it is and hope it's helpful. I'll cheerfully update it tomorrow if anyone has improvements to be made.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll try it out soon and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: For n edges, does building the list take O(n) time or O(n²) time? (O(n²) works for me. I'm just asking out of curiosity.)

Comment: It'll be O(n). The time for the macro expansion itself is trivial so even for large _n_ you're not looking at significant time. The greatest computational complexity happens in tikz for drawing the graph. Solving this problem was my first tikz experiment so I can't give much more detail than that.

Comment: This worked after I changed `\edef\mygraph` to `\xdef\mygraph`.

Comment: Oops, I accidentally left an incompletely reverted definition in the code. I'll fix above.