# Drawing a graph using macros for edges

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw graphs in TikZ, but it doesn't work as expected when using macros. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\def\myedge#1#2{"#1" -> "#2"}
\begin{document}
% this works as expected
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[nodes={draw, circle}, layered layout, sibling distance=8mm, level distance=8mm] {
"a" -> "b";
"a" -> "c";
"b" -> "d";
"b" -> "e";
};
\end{tikzpicture}

% this doesn't work as expected
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[nodes={draw, circle}, layered layout, sibling distance=8mm, level distance=8mm] {
\myedge{a}{b};
\myedge{a}{c};
\myedge{b}{d};
\myedge{b}{e};
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the second picture, I get 0 edges and 4 nodes: `"a" -> "b"`, `"a" -> "c"`, `"b" -> "d"`, `"b" -> "e"`, instead of 5 nodes and 4 edges.

[image: output: 2 graphs]

How can I make this work?

I'm actually trying to programmatically draw graphs ([detailed context](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565567/drawing-a-graph-using-commands-throughout-tex-file)), so the `\myedge` macro will get replaced by something more complicated. I thought of using PGF directly instead of using TikZ, but I couldn't find any examples for this in the pgf manual. In fact, if it's not too difficult, I'll prefer a PGF-based solution.

**Edit**: Based on the kind of answers I have got for this question, I think I should clarify more about what I'm trying to do.

There is a file `graph.tex` that looks something like this:

```
\myedge{a}{b}
\myedge{a}{c}
\myedge{b}{d}
\myedge{b}{e}
```

This file is generated automatically by a program, and I don't want to repeatedly mess with the source code of that program, so assume that `graph.tex` is fixed.

I want to `\input graph.tex` into `main.tex`, and I want to control the format of edges in `main.tex`. For example, if I want to change node labels from `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. to `Client a`, `Client b`, etc. or `Theorem \ref{a}`, `Theorem \ref{b}`, etc., then I should be able to do so from within `main.tex` just by changing the definition of `\myedge`.

This is basically separation of concerns: The program generating `graph.tex` shouldn't need to know what exactly the node labels are. It should only know which entities are linked to which other entities. The information about what exactly the node labels are should belong in `main.tex`.

Comment: it would be helpful to add a handrawn sketch of the desired output

Comment: @jsbibra the output (screenshot) contains two graphs. The first one (that looks like a tree) is desired. The second one (the 4 big nodes) is not.

Comment: does the answer given by member @Zarko satisfy your requirement

Comment: @jsbibra No, because Zarko's answer will only help me draw trees/forests, but my graphs need not be trees. My graphs can be arbitrary directed acyclic graphs.

Comment: please have alook at the answer below  if it meets the requirement

Answer (score 1):

I would not bother with TikZ `graph` and `graphdrawing`, with use of the `forest` package is simpler (at least to me) achieve your goals and solution works with pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX as well with LuaLateX engines. Also code is shorter:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14159 mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  myedge/.style={%
    for tree = {circle, draw, minimum size=1.1em, inner sep=0pt,
                l sep=8mm, s sep=8mm}
                }
        }
        
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest} myedge
[a  [c]
    [b  [d] [e]]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I should have taken a more representative example. My graph need not be a tree. It can be any directed acyclic graph.

Comment: This can be simple achieved by `forest`. I just reproduce shoved example.  With function `grow`it can be directed anywhere. See documentation for `forest` for all possible options or show some desired graph scenario.

Comment: grow won't help here. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this -- straight from the book

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary {graphs,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs,shapes.geometric}


\begin{document}

%\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikz
    \graph [
    grow down, branch right, nodes={circle,draw,minimum size=2em}] {
        "" -> h [] -> {
            c [] -> {
                a [],
                e []
            },
            j []
        }
    };



\tikz [new set=my nodes] {
    \node [set=my nodes, circle, draw] at (1,1) {A};
    \node [set=my nodes, circle, draw] at (1.5,0) {B};
    \node [set=my nodes, circle, draw] at (1,-1) {C};
    \node (d) [circle, draw] at (3,0) {D};
    \graph { X [circle,draw]-> (my nodes) -> (d) };
}




\tikz \graph [simple,nodes={circle,draw}] {
% The larger tree, no special options in force
a -> {
    b -> {c,d},
    e -> {f,g},
    h
},
{ [edges=red] % Now highlight a part of the tree
    a -> e -> {f,g}
}
};
%\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```